# How to disable Print Screen shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, print-screen

In my keyboard the <kbd>print screen</kbd> key is very close to the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, and whenever I want to press backspace, instead it takes a screenshot. How can I disable the <kbd>print screen</kbd> shortcut?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try changing it via

**System Settings → Hardware / Keyboard → Shortcuts → Screenshots → Take a screenshot**

To disable the shortcut, click the row so that it shows "New accelerator" as shown below and then press the backspace key.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 the option is no longer called `Take a screenshot` and is now called `Save a screenshot to Pictures`. To disable it, select it then hit `Backspace`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 21 it is `Settings / Keyboard Shortcuts / Save a screenshot to Pictures`. You may search for the shortcut by clicking the search icon located in the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

I disabled it with prejudice, because every cursor key event popped up the screenshot dialog and gnome-screenshot is the culprit. I'm mostly using LXDE and couldn't find where this is configured - the usual Linux problem - so I delete `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` and replaced it with a executable file with just `#` in it. This may not be efficient but does the job.

Comment: would it be a good idea if i backed the file then delete it, and copy it back before closing the app ?